# I can't open Flutter Inspector in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to setup environment for working with React-Native.
I installed Android studio, Dart and Flutter plugin for building application for android and apple mobile.
I can't open Flutter Inspector in Android Studio.
[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your app on an emulator or device to see the Flutter Inspector.

If you are running an emulator and this error still occurs then I have this from a comment on this issue on Github

I had the same problem, but then tried to run the code with another emulator, then it worked.

> Seems to be related to the emulator. The error occurs on the emulator.
>
> Emulator 1 (with error):
> Nexus 6, Q
> Emulated Performance, graphics: Hardware
>
> Emulator 2 (without error)
> Nexus 5X, Pie
> Emulated Performance, graphics: Auto
>
> Tried to change Emulator settings from hardware acceleration to auto. Didn't work.
> Anyway, I found a workaround and will continue for now.

[From Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3359#issuecomment-497641760)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you @CaldeiraG - I've edited the answer